# Clicking on a button with different id downloads the same file when it should download a different file

Tags: php

This is what I tried so far,when  I click on button 1 it downloads some.txt. When I click on button 2 the same thing happens instead of downloading blue.txt i get some.txt again. In my table when the user clicks on button 2 they should be able to download the blue.txt file only.

```html
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
include 'connection/connection.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["id"])) {

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$result = $con->query("select * from my_table where UserName='$username'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$log = $row['LoggedIn'];

if($log=='') {
 $id = $_SESSION["id"];
 $time = Now();
 $insert = $con->query("INSERT INTO my_table (LoggedIn) Values($time) WHERE id = '$id'");
}

else{
 $id = $_SESSION["id"];
 $update = $con->query("UPDATE my_table SET LoggedIn = Now() WHERE id = '$id'");
}

 if(isset($_POST['LogOut'])){
        header('Location:LogOut.php');
    }
}
/* need to add this later
else{
    header('Location: LogIn.php');
exit;
} */

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>User Api Docs</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <!--<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">API Docs User</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="LogOut.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <div class="text-center">
Welcome! <?php echo $row['UserName']; ?>. You are logged in. Your UserID is <?php echo $row['id'];?>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th style="text-align:center;">FileID</th>
  <th style="text-align:center;">FileName</th>
  <th style="text-align:center;">Download File</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php

$res = $con->query("select * from File_Table");
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $row['FileID']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['FileName']; ?></td>
  <td>
  <form action="user.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Download" id="<?php echo $row['FileID'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['FileID'];?>">
<?php
  $file_row = $row['FileID']; echo $file_row; $file_name = $row['FileName']; echo $file_name;
  if(isset($_POST['Download'])){ 
 
 $results = $con->query("select * from File_Table where FileID = '$file_row'");
if($rows = $results->fetch_assoc()){
 $uploading = $rows['FileName'];
 echo $uploading;
 $file = 'docs_uploaded/'. $uploading;
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
}
}
?>
  </form>
  </td>
   </tr>
<?php
}
?>
 </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's Javascript plugins) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: This will fail you `$time = Now();`. You'll get an undefined constant notice.

Comment: thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

You need put links or another script to download that files, the headers are send one time when your page is loaded for the browser.

```
<form action="download.php" method="post" >
    <input type="submit" name="fileID" id="fileID" value="<?php echo $row['FileID']; ?>">
</form>
```

download.php

```
<?php
//You need validate if your user user is logged on
if (isset($_POST['fileID']) && isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
    //Filter only int for avoid SQL injection or changed for prepared
    $iFile = filter_var($_POST['fileID'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $results = $con->query("select * from File_Table where FileID = '$iFile'");
    if ($rows = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $uploading = $rows['FileName'];
        echo $uploading;
        $file = 'docs_uploaded/' . $uploading;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            readfile($file);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the $_POST['Download'] <-where is this coming from

Comment: Thanks I will give it a shot soon

Comment: This didn't quite work I get redirected to download.php on each button click. However, I did figure it out with some help from a colleague

Comment: so I haven't posted solution because I am not able to read the file correctly. I tried switching content-type: application/text and still get html tags with it and my actual file text doesn't show up.